# Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint', referenced from method

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one user running my app getting the following error, which I can't reproduce on my phone or I haven't see on any other phone.

Can any one suggest why this isn't working just for this user, they say that the Googlemaps app works fine.
Note I have Google API and maps in my manifest too.

```
E/dalvikvm( 1978): Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint', referenced from method id.wilsononline.gcadroid.gcadroid$loadNearby.<init>
W/dalvikvm( 1978): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 522 (Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint;) in Lid/wilsononline/gcadroid/gcadroid$loadNearby;
D/dalvikvm( 1978): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x006b
D/dalvikvm( 1978): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0de1 at 0x7d in Lid/wilsononline/gcadroid/gcadroid$loadNearby;.<init>
W/dalvikvm( 1978): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint;)
W/dalvikvm( 1978): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint;)
W/dalvikvm( 1978): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint;)
I/dalvikvm( 1978): Could not find method com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint.getLatitudeE6, referenced from method id.wilsononline.gcadroid.gaLoadNearbyCaches.startLoadCaches
W/dalvikvm( 1978): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3554: Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint;.getLatitudeE6 ()I
D/dalvikvm( 1978): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
```

Comment: What device does the user have?

Comment: they have a Bauhn phone and tablet from Aldi here is a link to the Tablet http://www.bauhn.com.au/Products/10-1%E2%80%9D-Quad-Core-3G-Wi-Fi-Tablet.aspx  and phone :  http://www.aldi.com.au/au/html/offers/2827_25805.htm